# Which steps occur in each phase of Meiosis and Mitosis

Tags: cell-biology, meiosis, mitosis

MITOSIS

1. In mitosis am I correct in saying that the spindles attach to the centromeres at the end of prophase/prometaphase? (I read this in an answer to another question)

MEIOSIS

1. Does the nuclear envelope disintegrate during prophase (as occurs in mitosis), or during metaphase? (this is what it says on my textbook)
2. When do the spindles attach to the chromosomes during the first phase? (during prophase I, or anaphase I? On my textbook it says anaphase I)
3. And when do they attach to the sister chromatids in phase II? (on my textbook it says metaphase II).

Comment: Why would you doubt the answers you are reading in your textbook? It should be accurate, at least for a phenomena as well characterized as Mitosis and Meiosis.

Comment: Please limit yourself to one question per post.

Comment: Is there some reason that you doubt the textbook?

Comment: @rg255 I doubt the textbook because other reliable sources were giving contradicting information, and my teacher even mentioned that in some parts it was not specific/accurate enough.

Comment: Then you should give the sources for the both sides of the contradictory information

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mitosis:
1. Yes, the spindle fibers attach to centromeres at the prometaphase

http://www.biology.arizona.edu/cell_bio/tutorials/cell_cycle/cells3.html

Meiosis:
1. The nuclear membrane breaks down in Metaphase 1 and reforms during Telophase. It breaks down again in Prophase 2, reforming after that in Telophase 2 in the daughter cells.

2. The spindles attach to the centromere is Metaphase 1
3. Yes the spindles attach to the sister chromatids in Metaphase 2

Check out [this](http://highered.mheducation.com/sites/dl/free/0072886161/196644/stages_meiosis.html) animation, it might be pretty useful